# Debug multiple projects

Tags: development, visual-studio, debugging

I've got an issue when I want to debug two projects.
When I attach one of project to all Sharepoint process, VS hits correctly my breakpoints. But when I want to attach a second project, it doesn't want and display an error message on my breakpoint : "No symbols has been load for this document"

(I have to debug two projects because some methods are called on the second project)

Thanks you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may happen if:

1. The second project was built and deployed in `Release` mode, not in `Debug`.
2. Or if you deployed the correct debug version into the GAC (manually or with a WSP package deployment), but the SharePoint processes (SharePoint Timer, w3wp or else, depending on the component you're working on) were not restared after that.

Comment: I deploy from Sharepoint Shell, so how do I know if I deploy in Release or Debug ?

Comment: `Debug` vs `Release` is defined at compile-time, from Visual Studio settings. Once compiled, a DLL is either in Debug or Release mode, and you can't change it without the source code and recompilation.

Comment: Ok Thanks !
I have a plug-in in VS (CKS Dev) to debug more easily, and I just see that I can select multiple projects to achieve that.
But indeed, the second project was not the one on server farm.
Thanks you